# Cell borders not show on IE or Firefox

Tags: css

I wanted to add an icon on the bottom right corner of my calendar cell.

```
.dias td{
width: 13%;
height: 120px; 
background:  #fff;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
vertical-align: top;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
position: relative;

}
.diaCumple{
position: absolute;
bottom:0; /* top: 0; */
right:0; /* left: 0; */
z-index: 10;
text-align:right;
vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

It shows OK on Chrome, but table cells borders do not show on IE or FF.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/umxee3zm/10/)

[image: This is how they look]

Comment: Looks the exact same on Firefox 57.0. What versions of IE and firefox are you using? Also why are you using the JQuery tag? There isnt a single line of it in your question

Comment: Hi, please provide a [mcve] in the question itself rather than only linking to a 3rd party site like JSFiddle.

Comment: The `.diaCumple` element doesn't have a `td` in your JSFiddle. So I'm not sure how it's working at all in any browser with the selector `.diaCumple td`, same for the other selector. Something is missing.

Comment: I tried to duplicate the error in jsFiddle but I was unable to do it. Everything looks perfect on chrome but it doesnt work on IE11 or FF on my localhost. It must be something to do with bootstrap. I just removed the whole thing and worked it out differently. Because in the end, I didnt like how it looks.